# Calculating planned working hours based on department in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

In the attached file I have tried to subtract columns "out" from "in" to find planned working hours based on the department a person is working in.
[Sum two columns based on text.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdSWc_nRtbY59RhEqILtN5K_nvmMNH1Z/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104460105425863645392&rtpof=true&sd=true)
[image: Timesheet planned vs actuals]
Department VS and Cleaning should be summarized in the fields C22:O22

Trying to find a way to subtract C4:C20 from B4:B20 based on the Department column

`=IF(OR($B$4:$B$20="VS";$B$4:$B$20="Cleaning");TEXT((SUM(F4:F20)-SUM(E4:E20));"t");"")`

`=TEXT(SUM((IF(B4:B20="VS";SUM(D4:D20);0))-(IF(B4:B20="Cleaning";SUM(C4:C20);0)));"t")`

I am not sure what I can use to try to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no version constraints per your tags, you can use the `FILTER` function:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D$4:D$20-C$4:C$20,$B$4:$B$20="VS"))
```

*Adjust column references as appropriate for your data.*

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

`=SUM(C$4:D$20*($B$4:$B$20="VS")*{-1,1})`

For older Excel use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM